# Get Rank for Contest use Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core, rank, row-number

I have the following database

| UserId | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Jonh |
| 2 | Sam |
| 3 | Harry |

| ContestId | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Exam |

| UserId | ContestId |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 1 |

| ExerciseId | Name | ContestId |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Test A | 1 |
| 2 | Test B | 1 |

| SubmitId | ExerciseId | UserId | Point |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 10 |
| 2 | 1 | 1 | 20 |
| 3 | 2 | 1 | 30 |
| 4 | 2 | 1 | 40 |
| 5 | 1 | 2 | 50 |
| 6 | 1 | 2 | 80 |

***The result I wanted***

| Rank | UserName | Test A | Test B | Total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Sam | 80 | 0 | 80 |
| 2 | Jonh | 20 | 40 | 60 |
| 3 | Harry | 0 | 0 | 0 |

I tried:

```csharp
_UserContest.Select(x => new
{
    User = x.User,            //foreign key
    Submits = x.Contest.Exercises
        .SelectMany(y => y.Submits.Where(z => z.UserId == x.UserId).OrderByDescending(z => z.Point).Take(1))
        .ToList()
}).Select(x => new
{
    Name = x.User.Name,
    Submits = x.Submits.Select(y => new { Id = y.ExerciseId, Point = y.Point }),      //This list will be formatted as a row on the UI
    Total = x.Submits.Sum(y => y.Point)
}).OrderByDescending(x => x.Total).ToListAsync();
```

The result

```
[
    {
        "rank": 0,
        "name": "Sam",
        "submits": [
            {
                "id": "1",
                "point": 80,
            },
        ],
        "total": 80,
    },
    {
        "rank": 0,
        "name": "Jonh",
        "submits": [
            {
                "id": "1",
                "point": 20,
            },
            {
                "id": "2",
                "point": 40,
            },
        ],
        "total": 60,
    },
    {
        "rank": 0,
        "name": "Harry",
        "submits": [],
        "total": 0,
    },
]
```

Then, I found the library [Thinktecture.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Thinktecture.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer) support row number. I corrected my query

```csharp
_UserContest.Select(x => new
{
    User = x.User,            //foreign key
    Submits = x.Contest.Exercises
        .SelectMany(y => y.Submits.Where(z => z.UserId == x.UserId).OrderByDescending(z => z.Point).Take(1))
        .ToList()
}).Select(x => new
{
    Rank = EF.Functions.RowNumber(EF.Functions.OrderByDescending(x.Submits.Sum(y => y.Point))),
    Name = x.User.Name,
    Submits = x.Submits.Select(y => new { Id = y.ExerciseId, Point = y.Point }),      //This list will be formatted as a row on the UI
    Total = x.Submits.Sum(y => y.Point)
}).ToListAsync();
```

But, it's not what i expected

```
[
    {
        "rank": 1,
        "name": "Sam",
        "submits": [
            {
                "id": "1",
                "point": 80,
            },
        ],
        "total": 80,
    },
    {
        "rank": 2,
        "name": "Jonh",
        "submits": [
            {
                "id": "1",
                "point": 20,
            },
            {
                "id": "2",
                "point": 40,
            },
        ],
        "total": 60,
    },
    {
        "rank": 4,      //it's exactly 3
        "name": "Harry",
        "submits": [],
        "total": 0,
    },
]
```

Please help me fix it or a better query, thanks.

Comment: It is Pivot query. There is no direct LINQ translation if count of columns is dynamic. Better to use  pure SQL.

Comment: thanks your answer, I will try Pivot, but I still want to solve it on EF Core if possible

Comment: Search SO, about LINQ and PIVOT.